# How to send a POST request to sellix in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to use sellix.io API to create a payment in PHP, everything works fine in local until I upload the code to the webhost, there I get:

> {"status":400,"data":null,"message":null,"log":null,"error":"Transaction flagged as potential fraud (xxxxxxxxxxx).","env":"production"}

It says my request is flagged as a potential fraud. Asking around I got told that "sending a payment request from a server which can be considered a VPN or a RDP with no useragent nor fingerprint of that device may be flagged"

How can I send the request with a proper useragent? or fingerprint?
this is the code I've been using:

```php
<?php
    $mail = $_GET["mail"];
    $url = "https://dev.sellix.io/v1/payments";

    $data = json_encode(array(
        "title" => "MyProduct",
        "product_id" => "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "gateway" => "PAYPAL",
        "value" => 20,
        "currency" => "EUR",
        "quantity" => 1,
        "email" => $mail,
        "white_label" => false,
        "return_url" => "https://dev.sellix.io/v1/return" //not sure what this is supposed to do...
    ));

    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
       // "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n" .
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx(API KEY)xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    ));
    echo $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    $finalUrl = strval(json_decode($response)->data->url);
    header("Location: $finalUrl"); //redirects the current page to the payment page.
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a guess based on the lack of information related to your question on [their help page](https://help.sellix.io/en/articles/4511685-fraud-prevention) and [API documentation](https://developers.sellix.io/#product-create). I have listed some tips in the order I would try to debug this:

## 1: Sending user agent header

Try adding the user-agent header of your client. this will be available in `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`

```php
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        "User-agent: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']."\r\n" .
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx(API KEY)xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    ));`
```

Caveat: If you are doing some custom ajax you may not get the header. You can also provide a static value, but essentially avoiding fraud is in your best interest.

## 2: Adding a fingerprint header/cookie

Fingerprinting is (apparently) sending information to identify the browser. according to [this OWASP article](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/JSON_Web_Token_for_Java_Cheat_Sheet.html#implementation-example_1) it could be stored in a cookie called `__Secure-Fgp` which you would have to add to the request.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17828740/which-request-headers-can-be-used-for-a-browser-client-fingerprint) goes some way to show one method of calculating the firngerprint client side.

Disclaimer: I have not tried this myself. and I would query their support if there is a header this would fit into.

## 3: Debugging with another product

According to their help page you can set the `"max_risk_level"` to *100* on a `POST /products` call, in order to turn off their fraud engine **DO NOT DO THIS IN PRODUCTION** fraud prevention mechanics are there to prevent you from being cheated as well. But it may help you to find out what is going wrong and getting a proof of concept up and running.